# How to change the font size in a ganttchart?

Tags: pgfgantt

How do I change the font size in a ganttchart? I tried putting in the scriptsize command in the same place like a table environment but it does not change anything.

```
\begin{ganttchart}{1}{16}
  \scriptsize
  \gantttitle{Research Plan}{16} \\
  \gantttitle{Year 1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 4}{4} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 2}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 3}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 4}{1}{2} \\
\end{ganttchart}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different keys for setting font characteristics.  The ones that apply to your chart include `title label font` and `bar label font`, however, I have specified others that may be relevant for different charts, as well.

To ascertain these, I searched the documentation for `label font`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  title label font=\tiny,
  bar label font=\tiny,
  group label font=\tiny,
  milestone label font=\tiny,
  today label font=\tiny,
  vrule label font=\tiny]{1}{16}
  \gantttitle{Research Plan}{16} \\
  \gantttitle{Year 1}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 2}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 3}{4}
  \gantttitle{Year 4}{4} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 2}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 3}{1}{2} \\
  \ganttbar{Task 4}{1}{2} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: According to documentaion, multiple commands seem to be allowed. How to change, say, both font size and style simultaneously?